# Font of UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput UIAlertView not changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

The font of a `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` styled `UIAlertView` can't be changed:

```
alert.alertViewStyle               = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

UITextField* textField             = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField.textAlignment            = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
textField.autocorrectionType       = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textField.font                     = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0f];
```

The other properties shown here are changed.

What am I missing?  This is with iOS 6.1 SDK running on iOS 7 GM.